# can't run my newly installed ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, system-installation, login

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 14.04 via boot stick, I restarded my computer - everything worked perfectly fine. When I booted the system again later that day nothing worked after  logging myself in. Only the start up picture with Ubuntu 14.04 written on the lower left side and the curser is shown. Plus it's saying, that it's connected to the internet. I tried to log in with the guest account -same. I restarted a million times - nothings changes. I didn't do anything when I logged in the first time. Do I have to reinstall Ubuntu or is there a more simple solution? Can this be a hardware thing, since my laptop is about 7 years old and has its flaws?

P.S.: I don't usually speak english and my computer skills don't go beyond installing a new system and copying things into the terminal, which I'm not able to open when I can't log in.